# Why C# compiler treated string class separately with foreach statement

Tags: c#, foreach

I clearly understand ["Pattern-based" approach](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/06/30/following-the-pattern.aspx) that uses C# compiler when it dealing with the `foreach` statement.

And from C# Language Specification (section 8.8.4) it is clear that first of all C# compiler tries to find `GetEnumerator` method and only then tries to find `IEnumerable<T>` and `IEnumerable` interfaces.

But its unclear for me, why C# compiler treats `string` separately (because the `String` class contains a method `GetEnumerator` that returns [`CharEnumerator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.charenumerator.aspx) and it also implements `IEnumerable<char>` and `IEnumerable` interfces):

```
string s = "1234";
foreach(char c in s)
  Console.WriteLine(c);
```

converts to

```
string s = "1234";
for(int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
  Console.WriteLine(s[i]);
```

But I can't find any exceptions in Language Specification regarding the `String` class. Could someone give some insights about this solution?

I tried with the C# 4 compiler. Here is the IL code for the previous code snippet:

```
IL_0000:  ldstr       "1234"
IL_0005:  stloc.0     
IL_0006:  ldloc.0     
IL_0007:  stloc.2     
IL_0008:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0009:  stloc.3     
IL_000A:  br.s        IL_001E
IL_000C:  ldloc.2     
IL_000D:  ldloc.3     
IL_000E:  callvirt    System.String.get_Chars
IL_0013:  stloc.1     
IL_0014:  ldloc.1     
IL_0015:  call        System.Console.WriteLine
IL_001A:  ldloc.3     
IL_001B:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_001C:  add         
IL_001D:  stloc.3     
IL_001E:  ldloc.3     
IL_001F:  ldloc.2     
IL_0020:  callvirt    System.String.get_Length
IL_0025:  blt.s       IL_000C
```

Comment: my guess would be that it's an internal optimization for the String class (or even some legacy code). When building a compiler, you can choose whatever method you want for your internal class.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Good catch. I was aware that the compiler performed a similar optimization for arrays, but I didn't know that it did this for strings too.

The best I can get you is a call-out from the [language specification](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=7029) that gives a compiler the right to stray from the 'canon' as long as it produces equivalent behaviour:

> **8.8.4 The foreach statement**
>
> [...]  A foreach statement of the form
>   `foreach (V v in x)` *embedded-statement*
>   is then expanded to:

```
{
    E e = ((C)(x)).GetEnumerator();
    try {
        V v;
        while (e.MoveNext()) {
            v = (V)(T)e.Current;
            embedded-statement
        }
    }
    finally {
        … // Dispose e
    }
}
```

> [...] **An implementation is permitted
>   to implement a given foreach-statement
>   differently, e.g. for performance
>   reasons, as long as the behavior is
>   consistent with the above expansion.**

Comment: Thanks, Ani. You explanation seems reasonable.